# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 exception Emask SAct SErr action 0x6 frozen

Tags: dual-boot, windows, ssd, reset

I have a Kingston Predator PCIe 240 GB SSD (AHCI device.)  I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7 64-bit.  If I boot Ubuntu from poweroff, everything is fine.  But if I boot after restarting from Windows, I get long pauses and see the following in dmesg:

```
[Fri May 15 02:53:50 2020] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfbdff000 port 0xfbdff100 irq 36
[Fri May 15 02:53:50 2020] ata7: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Fri May 15 02:53:50 2020] ata7.00: ATA-8: Kingston SHPM2280P2H/240G, OC34L5TP, max UDMA/133
[Fri May 15 02:53:50 2020] ata7.00: 468862128 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[Fri May 15 02:53:50 2020] ata7.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Fri May 15 02:54:26 2020] ata7.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xc0000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[Fri May 15 02:54:26 2020] ata7.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri May 15 02:54:26 2020] ata7.00: cmd 60/08:90:98:1f:de/00:00:14:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 4096 in
[Fri May 15 02:54:26 2020] ata7.00: status: { DRDY }
```

My question is: Is there a way (e.g., kernel parameter) I can force a reset of the storage controller during the boot process so that it is in its default poweroff configuration?  Apparently, the controller is in whatever configuration Windows had it when I restarted, and Ubuntu doesn't like that.

Thanks.